# (scheme) How to repeatedly add (or multiple) elements in list?

Tags: list, scheme

This function is supposed to multiple the two lists of unary numbers represented with l's together. Since multiplying is just adding repeatedly, I made a function that added the lists and used this function to loop it until it reached the end of one of the lists.

For example:

```
~ (um1 '(l l l) '(l l))
 (l l l l l l) <--- 3 * 2 = 6
```

The problem is that it isn't looping right. It's adding a lot of extra numbers. Help?

```
;adds ls1 and ls2
(define (uadd ls1 ls2)
  (if (null? ls1) ls2
   (cons (car ls1) (uadd (cdr ls1) ls2))))

;multiplies ls1 and ls2
(define (um1 ls1 ls2)
  (define (help ls1 ls2 i)
    (if (<= i (length ls2))
      (help (uadd ls1 ls1) ls2 (add1 i))
    ls1))
(help ls1 ls2 0))
```

PS: Sorry for asking so many questions. I'm REALLY struggling in my computer science class.

Answer (score 0):

`(a+1)*b = b + a*b`. Use that.

You do: `a*b = (h a b 0) = if (i<b) then (h (a+a) b (i+1)) else a`. It doesn't make sense to me, sorry. You double the first arg on each iteration of `help`, and you iterate `b` times. This seems to calculate `2^b*a`.

Your first code is fine. Your second suffers from *shadowing* - you have same names for the arguments in your helper as in your main function, and where you intended to use one you end up using another. Rename the vars and all will be well:

```
;multiplies ls1 and ls2
(define (um1 ls1 ls2)
  (define (help a b i)
    (if (< i (length b))
      (help (uadd a ls1) b (add1 i))
      a))
(help ls1 ls2 1))
```

This of course can be much improved, efficiency-wise. You don't need to pass `ls2` to the helper, and you don't need to recalculate its length all the time. Don't forget also that `a*0 = 0`.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple if we go back to the definition of multiplication - it's an abbreviated sum. What is `(um1 '(l l l) '(l l))` ? the same as `'(l l l)` *appended* to `'(l l l)`. No need to define a helper here, it's not even necessary to use `uadd` - the trick is knowing how to combine lists together to form a list with the elements of both (hint: this we're *not* using `cons`), and repeating this process as many times as needed.

Let's say, that the first list is to be "repeated" a number of times equal to the number of elements in the second list - and the recursion will end when the second list runs out of elements. You know the drill, fill-in the blanks:

```
(define (um1 ls1 ls2)
  (if <???>                       ; if the list we're recurring over is empty
      <???>                       ; ... you know what to return
      (<???> <???>                ; otherwise add one copy of the list we're repeating
             (um1 <???> <???>)))) ; and advance the recursion over the correct list
```

Don't forget to test the procedure, noticing what happens when one of the lists is empty:

```
(um1 '() '())
=> '()
(um1 '(l) '())
=> '()
(um1 '() '(l))
=> '()
(um1 '(l) '(l l))
=> '(l l)
(um1 '(l l) '(l))
=> '(l l)
(um1 '(l l l) '(l l))
=> '(l l l l l l)
(um1 '(l l) '(l l l))
=> '(l l l l l l)
```

Comment: So, I should use append instead of cons?

Answer (score 0):

There's a much easier way to do this than with an extra helper - your "uadd" procedure is your helper.

What is any kind of multiplication?

"3*4=12" or "a*b=c"

"3+3+3+3=12" or "a+a+a+a=c" or "a value added itself a b number of times equals c"

Thus, our pseudocode:

"If either ls1 or ls2 = 0 (or null), the answer is 0 (or null)" <-- BASE CASE

"Otherwise, add ls1 to itself & remove and decrement ls2, until there's nothing left in ls2" <-- RECURSION

Piecing it together:

```
(define um1
    (lambda (ls1 ls2)
        (cond
            [(or (null? ls1) (null? ls2)) '()] ;BASE
            [else (uadd ls1 (um1 ls1 (cdr ls2))]))) ;RECURSION
```

In our tail recursion, we only want to decrement ls2 by one until it's '(), in which case, our BASE CASE catches it and feeds a '() on top of which is stacked an ls2-number of

```
(uadd ls1 (uadd ls1 (uadd ls1 (...ls2-number-of-times, until: '() ))))
```